# Full-letter cursor in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I just started using Vim within a bash terminal. Often the cursor is very hard to see, it being a tiny line among hundreds of characters that are the same color.

I'd like to change my cursor to be of full-letter width, like so:
[image: full-letter cursor]

What would be the command to put on my `.bashrc` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this via your .bashrc ([this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55423/how-to-change-cursor-shape-color-and-blinkrate-of-linux-console) may help with that), but for me, using Gnome Terminal, I just changed it by going to Edit -> Preferences -> Profile -> Text and set "Cursor shape" there to "Block".